# Fiddler - ReadResponse failed: The server did not return a response for this request

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

This was the first time I encountered this kind of error after dealing with RESTful web service in couple of times. I find it hard to trace the cause of error, hope you could help me.

I have this attribute for Login service

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Login?username={username}&password={password}&ip={ip}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Using fiddler to use the service:

GET    http://localhost:3445/Authenticate/Login?username=jsm&password=a&ip=1

[image]

Fiddler response:

```
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

[image]

I'm not sure if it caused by, `Content-type: application/json` because when I try to change it to xml:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Login?username={username}&password={password}&ip={ip}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
```

It gives me this result:

[image]

Kinda weird. What I have done wrong? I have to return json object.. Thanks!

Comment: I think I have to change the tool I use for testing Rest. To all who were able to read this question, what tool can you suggest for testing Rest? A tool that is capable of using protocols like POST, GET, PUT etc.. A tool aside from fiddler..? thanks

Comment: fiddler has been pretty good for me. Your issue above is not uncommon with `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`. I like in Fiddler looking at the RAW tab.

Comment: Can you try to remove the ResponseFormat attribute from your WebGet atrribute and check if it works. The default is xml but if you specify your content-type to application/json the WCF Rest Api is intelligent to reply back in the format that the client understands

Comment: @Rajesh It will work but it will return xml data, not data in Json format.

Comment: Can you post your method skeleton. Also post your config being used for the above service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of error is the loading of bunch data types (see the preview of xml data above). Json has a limit of approximately 65K objects, and in my project it exceeds the limit. So the final solution is to create DTO - "Data Transfer Object" that will minimize the data to be passed.

Comment: Do you have any info on where that 65k number came from? I've been Googling around about the max objects in JSON and can't find any info about it or potentially how to increase it, as I've run into the same issue (and I've already pared down with a DTO. 13k+ objects with 6 fields each)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error couple times because of different issues. Main reason is that wcf cant serialize the object.

in my first case it was because, the returned object is not the correct object that is stated in service. the service should have returned student object, but I was returning the studentExtended object(inherited object).

in my second case it was because of dateTime property which was in form that is not serializable (it was null). so I have changed it to DateTime.now so after that it was working again

Regards

Comment: my answer helped me a year later : )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed:. The resolution for me was: In IIS, recycle the application pools in where the app resides.

Answer (score 0):

> > I was using Xampp and Installed Fiddler...Same Error occured...
> >
> > **I run IIS for just Once** (As it was stopped due to running Xampp) and Everything went fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Finally, found the issue in defining the Contract type for the return object.

I have replaced [DataMember] to [EnumMember] as described below:

```
[DataContract]
public enum DiscountType
{
    [EnumMember]
    NONE = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    PERCENTAGE_DISCOUNT = 1
}
```

This fixed my "[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed" error which took my half day effort.