# WCF Restful service not sending response to web client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using MVC5, WebAPI, WCF Restful service in my web application.

When I rum WCF restful service I get mixed response. Some services gives me appropriate response and some not. I am running this application on my machine.

I used Fiddler to debug the service.

Success:

```
localhost/UserRestService.svc/api/GetMembership/23
```

Failure:
localhost/UserRestService.svc/api/GetUserProfile/xyz@gmail.com

> Error: [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a
>   response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

I am not able to understand this error. I googled it and could not resolve this error.

Please help.

Code:

WCF Service Interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/api/GetUserProfile/{userName}",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    // UserProfiles 
    UserProfile GetUserProfile(string userName);
```

Fiddler raw request

```
GET localhost:37181/UserRestService.svc/api/GetUserProfile/abc@gmail.com HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:37181
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1; lang=auto; __RequestVerificationToken=XCXv18_vpGu9UO4wian60eLRZqUQi6_
```

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in the service code? Is the service getting called at all? Also, saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425288/fiddler-readresponse-failed-the-server-did-not-return-a-response-for-this-req

Comment: @rmayer06: When I put breakpoint on the service, it gives appropriate response. But at the end, browser shows me the above error.

Comment: Something is happening between your service and the return to the web service. Perhaps a serialization error? Do you have the MS source and can you step through the code after your code?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape the @ symbol, it has reserved meaning in a URI.