# JSON Increase Maximum Number of Objects

Tags: .net, json, web-services, wcf, fiddler

I have a WCF web service built in C#.NET that is returning many many records (13k+) from a SQL database, being returned in JSON format. I'm running into a problem with the number of records being returned in the web service call- the problem appears to be the sheer number of objects, not the amount of data.

I found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425288/fiddler-readresponse-failed-the-server-did-not-return-a-response-for-this-req) that claims the max number of "objects" allowed in a JSON return is limited to around 65k. After returning my 13k+ records with all of their sub-properties (6 each) I appear to have surpassed that limit. If I try to make the call to my service and return all records, I get the following error headers in Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Date: Tue, 29 Jul 2014 13:16:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
```

However, if I switch my Stored Procedure in SQL to only return `TOP 10000`, everything works fine and my data comes through perfectly.

As stated earlier, it doesn't appear to be the size of the returned object- by scaling up from the amount of data that `TOP 10000` returns, my full result set would be around 1.4-1.5 MB, and I have my `web.config` file set up to allow a max JSON size of much much more than that:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="wellOver10GB" />
    ...
```

Has anyone else run into this problem of too many objects and found a solution? Is there a way to increase this limit, or is my problem possibly unrelated to this limit and actually something else I'm not seeing?

Comment: You may need to adjust the limit within IIS. Highly recommend Newtonsoft JSON parser. Also, see this page: http://www.ziggytech.net/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/

Comment: @lcryder adjust what limit within IIS? I'm not seeing anything that I can adjust. Parsing the JSON isn't the problem, because it's not even being received in the first place.

Comment: I was referring to this area of IIS (it may not apply). http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: @lcryder unfortunately, it does not apply. That section deals with maximums for the _request_ that is sent from the client, not the _response_ that is sent back.

Comment: @lcryder I found a solution if you are still curious- ended up being something that needed to be set in the WCF project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.MaxItemsInObjectGraph` that needs to be adjusted in order to return more objects. This can be done in the following way in the WCF project:

```
...
namespace _WSProjectName
{
    [ServiceBehavior(MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 1000000)] // Just did a million in my case, can be whatever you want to set it to
    public class ServiceName : IServiceName
    {
        ...
```

According to the [MSDN documentation on ServiceBehaviorAttribute.MaxItemsInObjectGraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.maxitemsinobjectgraph(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Use the `MaxItemsInObjectGraph` property set a limit on the number of items in an object graph that are serialized.

The documentation states that the default value is **65,536** (2^16)